# How to specify JVM Parameters inside Spring Boot Project when executed with init.d

Tags: spring-boot, jvm-arguments, init.d

I have a Spring Boot project that I'm running as an executable jar started as an init.d service on Linux.

I understand I can create a .conf file with the same name as the jar file to specify JVM parameters.  However, I would ideally like to "hard code" some parameters so there is no risk of the .conf file being missing.  This is a real risk as each deployment will have a different jar name because of the version number.

Also I know I can set the environment variable JAVA_OPTS, but I'm not sure how to do this if I'm launching the Spring Boot as a init.d service using a symlink to the jar file.

Lastly I know I can replace the init.d script completely using the [embeddedLaunchScript](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/repackage-mojo.html#embeddedLaunchScript) parameter, but I fell this overkill for what I want to accomplish and would want updates to the script in further releases.

Is there a way to specify JVM parameters in the Maven plugin or some other programmatic method?

Alternatively is there a way to hard code a static CONF file name?  Looking at the [embeddedLaunchScriptProperties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-when-it-written) it looks like confFolder can the folder, but not the name of the .conf file.

Comment: I think I have a full understanding of options, but want to make sure I'm not missing something before entering a feature request for improving the Maven plugin to allow JVM parameters to be passed through to the embeddedLaunchScript - Thanks

Comment: I think this answer is a solution for your problem: https://serverfault.com/a/462073

Comment: If I understand that answer, it involves creating a custom script and making that script a service using init.d  I understand that is an option but end goal is deploy the file with the parameters, so the embeddedLaunchScript is equivalent to that answer.

Comment: Found some commentary on this request https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2797

Comment: FYI, https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2797 has been re-opened and I'm implementing the solution.  I'll put the answer when it is available in a release.

Comment: [How to use inlinedConfScript to configure JAVA_OPTS with maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58763182/how-to-use-inlinedconfscript-to-configure-java-opts-with-maven) Hope to get your help！

Comment: Post a question.  I think if you remove the leading slash it will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Spring boot 2.0, you can set the `inlinedConfScript` property of the build plugin.  You can now reference a file that includes the appending or overwriting the JAVA_OPTS variable before the application starts.  More details can be found in the [Spring Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/deployment-install.html#deployment-script-customization-when-it-written).